# Using JS dynamic variables in Fixture

Tags: automated-tests, open-source, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I am using open-source TestCafe for the first time. I have 3 JS dynamic variables that I need to use in the fixture but I do not know how to enter them because of the name of the variables changes.

```
//I have this code, the 3 variables below are dynamic and I do not know how to         
//define them for the test to work 
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture `Getting Started`;  
    .page `http://mypage/example`;

test('My First Test', async t => {
    await t
        .typeText('#_19ea794cf2c5da', 'John.Smith@mail.com') //e-mail
        .typeText('#_1f5041dd561eb6', 'John Smith') //name
        .typeText('#_1ba6e017739c70', '5515675800') //telephone
});
```

The connection is executed but marks error in the first dynamic variable

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the way to locate elements. There are several ways to locate elements with dynamically generated IDs:

- using the [CSS Attribute Ends With](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_end.asp) Selector (see this [answer](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T240378/testcafe-how-to-get-dynamic-id-from-scripting))
- using CSS selectors connected with class name, tag name and etc.
- using the hierarchy selector methods ([parent](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/functional-style-selectors.html#parent), [child](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/functional-style-selectors.html#child) and etc.)